# HTTP Java script reqeust returning nothing

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

Why is this code not working?

```
    function sendHttprequest    (uRL)
        {
with (   new XMLHttpRequest ()){
open('get' ,uRL)

send ( void 0)

  console . log ("RESPONSETEXT:",responseText);;
    }
        }
```

It's supposed to make an HTTPS get request to the specified url. Plz help!

i got this code from freecodecamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t access the response after making the XMLHttpRequest. You have to set an `onload` handler to wait for the request to finish and then get the response when it loads. The usage of `with` indicates outdated code and it’s not recommended.

So, your code, corrected:

```
function sendRequest(url) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function (e) {
        console.log('response', request.responseText);
    };
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
}
```

and if you *must* use `with`:

```
function sendRequest(url) {
    with (new XMLHttpRequest()) {
        onload = function (e) {
            console.log('response', responseText);
        };
        open("GET", url);
        send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the open method you are missing the async parameter that should be supplied.
Below is an example taken from w3schools. Visit https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp for more information.

```
    function loadDoc() {
          var xhttp;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
             // code for modern browsers
              xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           } else {
              // code for IE6, IE5
              xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
              xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
           }
         };
         xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
         xhttp.send();
     }
```